# Explicitly determining the propagator for the dual field

Tags: field-theory, propagator, duality

So I have a question which has been on my mind for some time but I never got around to asking: how can I calculate the propagator for a dual field?

Let me go into some more detail. Starting off with the Lagrangian:
$ \hat{L}=\frac{1}{2}\Big( \partial_\mu \phi\Big)^2$, we can find the propagator (we can write this in several forms):
$$[\phi^+(t,x),\phi^-(0,y)]=-\frac{1}{4\pi }\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \text{ln}\Big[\frac{(x-y)^2-(t+i\epsilon)^2}{a^2} \Big]. $$

It is often convenient to define the dual field: $$\vartheta(t,x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} dx' \partial_0 \phi(x').$$ This can be thought of as being nonlocal, due to the integration, while the field $\phi$ is local.

How would you go about calculating:
$[\vartheta^+(t,x),\vartheta^-(0,y)]$?

I tried substituting in the above definition but was left with an integral in the end. I often see this above expression with some "stiffness" $K$ (like in a Luttinger liquid) in it and the Hamiltonian is of the form: $$\hat{H}=\frac{1}{K}(\partial_x \phi^2)+K(\partial_x \vartheta)^2.$$ The above propagator would be modified by multiplying by $\frac{1}{K}$ and I believe the dual fields propagator would be of the same form but by multiplying by $K$. I think this because of duality transforms: $K\rightarrow K^{-1}$.

Is this right? If so, how can I show this from the definition of $\varphi$ opposed to arguing the form from duality.